# Optimal Buffer Sizing

Tags: c, performance, memory-management, buffer

I guess this is a performance computing question. I'm writing a program in C which produces a large amount of output, much more than can typically be stored in RAM in its entirety. I intend to simply write the output to `stdout`; so it may just be going to the screen, or may be being redirected into a file. My problem is how to choose an optimal buffer size for the data that will be stored in RAM?

The output data itself isn't particularly important, so let's just say that it's producing a massive list of random integers.

I intend to have 2 threads: one which produces the data and writes it to a buffer, and the other which writes that buffer to `stdout`. This way, I can begin producing the next buffer of output whilst the previous buffer is still being written to `stdout`.

To be clear, my question isn't about how to use functions like `malloc()` and `pthread_create()` etc. My question is purely about how to choose a number of bytes (512, 1024, 1048576) for the optimal buffer size, which will give the best performance?

Ideally, I'd like to find a way in which I could choose an optimal buffer size dynamically, so that my program could adjust to whatever hardware it was being run on at the time. I have tried searching for answers to this problem, and although I found a few threads about buffer size, I couldn't find anything particularly relevant to this problem. Therefore, I just wanted to post it as a question in the hope that I could get some different points of view, and come up with something better than I could on my own.

Answer (score 6):

It's a big waste of time to mix design and optimization. This is considered one of the [top canonical mistakes.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize) It is likely to damage your design and not actually optimize much.

Get your program working, and if there is an indication of a performance issue, then profile it and consider analyzing the part that's really causing the problem.

I would think this applies particularly to a complex architectural optimization like multithreading your application. Multithreading a single image is something you never really *want* to do: it's impossible to test, prone to unreproducible bugs, it will fail differently in different execution environments, and there are other problems.  But, for some programs, multithreaded parallel execution is required for functionality or is one way to get necessary performance. It's widely supported, and essentially it is, at times, a necessary evil.

It's not something you want in the initial design without solid evidence that programs like yours need it.

Almost any other method of parallelism (message passing?) will be easier to implement and debug, and you are getting lots of that in the I/O system of your OS anyway.

Comment: Writing to stdout can be painfully slow, especially when not redirected to a file. Any performance gains from optimizing buffer size will likely be unnoticeable.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said in the question. I do have a working program. But at the moment it's just sequential. It produces one piece of output, writes that to `stdout`, then loops. This is why I'm now considering how to increase performance.

Comment: Aha. So, how about putting the buffering downstream?  In fact, just use the already-installed `dd(1)` program for it: `$ a.out | dd bs=128k`

Comment: Cool, I hadn't thought of that. I'm not sure how it would impact performance though?! My program would still only have one thread, which would sometimes be doing calculations and producing output, and sometimes be writing to `stdout`. I'll definitely give it a try though, thanks.

Comment: I/O through a pipe or to local disk is fast. To a terminal, not so much, because font rendering is so insanely complex these days. But I suspect your real concern is just that the program not block while a human is reading, so the downstream pipe-connected buffer should solve your problem. (If I understand it correctly.)

Comment: Could I ask what you mean by: "block while a human is reading"? I always just assumed that when outputting to the screen, a program outputs as quickly as possible and is just limited by unavoidable factors, like font rendering. Is this correct, or are there additional (avoidable) delays introduced by the terminal/shell for the users' benefit?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer: Measure it.**

Long answer: From my experience, it depends too much on the factors that are hard to predict in advance. On the other hand, you do not have to commit yourself before the start. Just implement a generic solution and when you are done, make a few performance tests and take the settings with the best results. A profiler may help you to concentrate on the performance critical parts in your program.

From what I've seen, those that produce the fastest code, often try the simplest, straightforward approach first. What the do better than the average programmers is that they have a very good technique at writing good performance tests, which is by far not trivial.

Without experience, it is easy to fall into certain traps, for example, ignoring caching effects, or (maybe in your application?!) underestimating the costs of IO operations. In the worst case, you end up squeezing parts of the program which do not contribute to the overall performance at all.

**Back to your original question:**

In the scenario that you describe (one CPU-bound producer and one IO-bound consumer), it is likely that one of them will be the bottleneck (unless the rate at which the producer generates data varies a lot). Depending on which one is faster, the whole situation changes radically:

Let us first assume, the IO-bound consumer is your bottleneck (doesn't matter whether it writes to stdout or to a file). What are the likely consequences?

Optimizing the algorithm to produce the data will not improve performance, instead you have to maximize the write performance. I would assume, however, that the write performance will not depend very much on the buffer size (unless the buffer is too small).

In the other case, if the producer is the limiting factor, the situation is reversed. Here you have to profile the generation code and improve the speed of the algorithm and maybe the communication of the data between the reader and the writer thread. The buffer size, however, will still not matter, as the buffer will be empty most of the time, anyway.

Granted, the situation could be more complex than I have described. But unless you are actually sure that you are not in one of the extreme cases, I would not invest in tuning the buffer size yet. Just keep it configurable and you should be fine. I don't think that it should be a problem later to refit it to other hardware environments.

Comment: You mean just trial and error: adjusting the buffer size in code, and running multiple times?!

Comment: @greydamian Basically yes. I know it sounds unsystematically but experiences shows that you very often make a-priori assumptions that do not hold in practice. Thus, starting simple and approaching the problem in a benchmark-driven approach often leads to good results.

Comment: Fair enough, I guess I could break out Valgrind. I was just hoping to generalise my program so that it could run well (not perfectly) on any machine, rather than tailoring it to a specific machine.

Comment: @greydamian I understand what you mean, but I don't think that benchmarking on a specific machine first will be a problem for you later. Unless the type of application is so demanding that you really have to use the characteristics of the architecture to produce a sufficient solution. For example, when developing a library for concurrent data structures. In that case, you really have to create a model of the architectures that you want to support and design specifically for that model.

Comment: Thank you for your addition to your original answer. My initial thought was that `stdout` would be the bottleneck for my program, and therefore I assumed that the best that I would be able to do was to keep `stdout` busy?! If this assumption was correct, I was hoping that someone could direct me to a programatic way in which to determine the throughput of `stdout` and hence determine the minimum buffer size that would keep it busy, or is trial-and-error (with profiling) still the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I personally think you are wasting your time.

First, run `time ./myprog > /dev/null`

Now, use  `time dd if=/dev/zero of=myfile.data bs=1k count=12M`.

`dd` is about as simple a program as you can get, and it will write the file pretty quickly. But writing several gigabytes still takes a little while. (12G takes about 4 minutes on my machine - which is probably not the fastest disk in the world - the same size file to /dev/null takes about 5 seconds).

You can experiment with some different numbers in `bs=x count=y` where the combination makes, the same size as your program output for the test-run.  But I only found that if you make VERY large blocks, it actually takes longer (1MB per write - probably because the OS needs to copy 1MB before it can write the data, then write it out and then copy the next 1MB, where with smaller blocks (I tested 1k and 4k), it takes a lot less time to copy the data, and there's actually less "disk spinning round not doing anything before we write to it").

Compare both of these times to your program running time. Is the time it takes to write the file the with `dd` much shorter than your program writing to the file?

If there isn't much difference, then look at the time it takes to write to /dev/null with your program - is that accounting for some or all of the difference?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You can definitely take that view that I'm wasting my time, as it could be argued that the performance increase itself won't be worth the time and effort in investigation. But I'm looking in to this more for my own personal interest, to improve my knowledge, and for my love of programming. I'll definitely look into the performance of `dd` as a comparison though.

Answer (score 0):

Most modern OSes are good at using the disk as a backing store for RAM. I suggest you leave the heuristics to the OS and just ask for as much memory as you want, till you hit a performance bottleneck.

Comment: I guess that I should have given some numbers in my question, sorry about that. At the moment, I'm running this software on a Linux system which has 4GB of RAM and 8GB of swap space, but the program can easily produce much more than 12GB of output. So, I'm thinking that something like `malloc(1670616516608)` would obviously be silly.

Comment: I presume you are writing out the generated data periodically or as soon as it fills a buffer? In that case, the size of the buffer would really depend on the speed at which the data is being generated, and not the amount of data. If the speed of data generation is very high compared to the throughput of stdout, I would suggest doing mmap on a file and using that memory. The actual buffer size will have to decided by trying it out with different sizes, for whatever IO policy you chose (mmap vs write)

Comment: My initial thought was that the overall performance of my program will be limited by the speed at which I can write to `stdout`. Therefore, the best that I can do is keep `stdout` busy, and this is what will dictate the size of my buffer?!

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use buffering, the OS will automatically swap pages to the disk for you whenever necessary, you don't have to program that. The simples would be for you to leave in in RAM if you don't need to save the data, else you're probably better of saving it after generating the data, because it's better for the disk i/o.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Of course when that's possible, you are correct. As I commented on Darth Chatri's post, I guess that I should have really included some numbers in my question. I'm running this program on a Linux machine with 4GB of RAM and 8GB of swap space, and my program can easily produce more than 12GB of output. Hence, a call like `malloc(1670616516608)` would just be silly. Unfortunately, this is why I can't generate all of the data, and store it in a single buffer, before outputting that data.

Comment: In that case I would simply make the buffer as big as possible minus some reserve (4BG - 1.5BG) so 2.5BG or even 3GB (depending on other apps their memory usage). Then whenever the buffer is full and it is still writing to stdout then I still don't see another option then just waiting until your buffer is empty again. Not waiting for the buffer to be empty would result in constantly putting one byte in the buffer when one comes free. But except if your output isn't a constant stream it's pretty useless to have a buffer at all. Buffers are useful for for non continues streams of data.

Comment: I was hoping to find an answer that related the optimum buffer size to the average file size.  In the 1990s I came up with 32256 bytes (2^15 - 1 disk sector) as optimum but now that seems slow like it's causing a lot of thrashing.   There's really no substitute for setting up your own tests with your own typical data and coming up with a number.  Meanwhile use whatever seems handy, it'll probably work.